# Sentry 2 "A user was found to match all plain text credentials however hashed credential [password] did not match."

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I'm getting this error when a username matches, but a password doesn't. Which is good if you want a hacker to find they're using the correct email address to log in and can keep guessing the password.

What I would like to know is, how do I stop this message from showing up when they have entered a correct address, but wrong password?

In my View, I just have this...

```
@if($errors->has('login'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('login', ':message') }}</div>
        @endif
```

I'm using Sentry's default configuration, is there something I could just set to false so this message doesn't show? I would like it to show all the other error messages, just not this one as it's a pretty big security risk.

Any help on this would be grateful.

Comment: Is it a security risk, though? Surely the security resides in the password, especially considering a person's email address is something that is known to friends, family and other people who are very likely to know that said user is using your service in the first place...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You're right. Security through obscurity isn't real security.

Comment: It's not a public service, it's the admin part of a cms so I would consider it a security risk. Also, all our clients have their own personal business email which wouldn't necessarily be shown publicly as well.

Comment: I also feel like some clients who aren't I.T literate would get scared by this notification and end up ringing us saying "I've just seen this message, couldn't someone hack me in this way?". And having to repeatedly tell them that they aren't in any risk could get annoying. I would rather that all the clients feel as safe as possible and have no questions hanging over their heads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for sentry (and I would) recommend using a try catch on the server side validation routine instead. 
[Sentry Documentation](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry#authenticate)

Specifically catch the Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException and set your own error message

```
try
{
// Set login credentials
$credentials = array(
    'email'    => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'password' => 'test',
);

// Try to authenticate the user
$user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e)
{
 echo 'Wrong Login Info, try again.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this has worked perfectly. :)